# Windows Toast notification application icon colors inverted

Tags: windows, toast

I have a windows application with toast notifications (using Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification). The problem is that when the application has a dark icon and the dark windows theme is applied, the application icon is getting inverted colors in notifications (in popups and in action center). I'm talking about the icon in the attribution area according to this [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=builder-syntax#attribution-area). Is there any way to forbid the system to invert icon colors?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like windows takes the decision to invert the icon or not according to the colors of the pixels on the border of the image. A little enlightening of border pixels do the trick and the system stops inverting the colors.

Comment: have you found something else that could work? I need to use my organisations logo and it's a dark red. When I enlighten the border it looks like crap...

Comment: Nope. All what I had to do is make border with the same color but 2% transparency. It is completely unnoticable in my case

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm deciding whether to invert the icon doesn't seem to account for transparency.

So just like Grigoriy, I've added extra white lines to the icon, with the maximum possible translucency (1 out of 255, instead of 0 that's fully transparent), and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

We've had the same issue and we weren't to resolve it completley, there were still some test user where the icon got inverted.

In our particular case we were dveloping a win32 app which doesn't have separate icons for dark and light mode (I think in UWP you can specify different icon resolutions for different themes)

If you have an .ico file with with only 1 resolution windows will scale that icon based on the resolution of the screen. So if the icon gets scaled down, the 1px transparent white border will dissapear. We've solved this by manually trying how much border is needed for each icon at the most used resoltuions (720p, 1080p, 4k)